# Binary string of length 60 - most compact way to store

Tags: javascript, java, byte

I have binary strings of length 60 representing yes/no states for the minutes of an hour and I would like to write them to file in Java. My three objectives are that this should be

1. compact (better than saving as string)
2. enabling an easy way to rebuild my binary strings when reading the file from JavaScript
3. without using third party libraries

My first thought was to convert the string to a Long (8 bytes) and save as such, but it seems complicated to get my binary string back when reading the file in JavaScript due to floating point number format and mantissa length. What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can handle integers correctly up to 2<sup>53</sup>-1, so you can use standard methods if you split the 60-bit data in two, and store it as two 32-bit integers.

Alternatively, you could store the data e.g. as a 15-character hexadecimal string, and recode it into a binary string with something like this:

```js
function hex2bin(s) {
    return ("0000000000000000000000000000000" + parseInt(s.substr(0,8), 16).toString(2)).substr(-32)
    + ("000000000000000000000000000" + parseInt(s.substr(8,7), 16).toString(2)).substr(-28);
}
document.write(hex2bin("123456789ABCDEF"));
```

Or you could use a base-64 string to reduce the data size to 10 characters, and decode it with something like this:

```js
function base642bin(s) {
    var b = "", e = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) b += ("00000" + e.indexOf(s.charAt(i)).toString(2)).substr(-6);
    return b;
}
document.write(base642bin("EjRWeJq83v"));
```

If you use a built-in Java function for base-64 encoding, check which encoding table it uses (sometimes the `+` and `/` are substituted for other characters).

Comment: I had been staring at this for too long and could not see the rather obvious solution of splitting the string and using two ints -> still only 8 bytes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Long binary strings can be converted to BigInt and back to binary.

```
const big = BigInt('0b' + a);
// store, perform math, etc.
const binaryStr = big.toString(2);
```

This supports values greater than 253 - 1 (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). E.g. here is a 95-char binary string being converted:

```
BigInt('0b' + '10100000100100110110010000010101111011011001101110111111111101000000101111001110001111100001101')
24847893154024981730169397005n
```

The prefix `0b` tells the constructor that this is a binary representation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt